# Constructor and const reference

Tags: c++, constructor, nodes, copy-constructor, const-reference

I;m study C++ right now (started like 2 days ago) and I have some trouble with writing Copy C'tor of Node.
Node is a class as following:

```
template <class T>
class Node {
        T* data;
        Node<T>* next;
        friend class Iterator<T>;
    public:
        Node():data(NULL),next(NULL){}
        Node(const T& data):data(NULL),next(NULL){
                T* copy = new T(data);
                this->data = copy;
        }

        Node(const Node& node):data(NULL),next(NULL){

            Node<T> dummy;
            dummy.data = node.data;
            dummy.next = node.next;
            Node<T>* head=new Node(*dummy);
            *this = *head;
            while(dummy.next != NULL) {
                dummy = *(dummy.next);
                head = head->next;
                head = new Node(*dummy);
            }
        }
```

Note: I have operator* so *dummy results in T type.

Another Note: My public and private fields may be wrong - but I will deal with it later.

After you puked a bit, let's look at the Copy C'tor please.

It gets a const refernce of Node, and then I tried to create a pointer to it. The compiler outputs an error:
`Node<T>* dummy= &node;` results `invalid conversion from 'const Node<int>*' to 'Node<int>*'` (I have a short main trying to create `Node<int>`).

Ok, so it seems like I can't create a pointer to a const, so I tried to copy it's fields manualy as shown in code.
When I run Eclipse debugger and check if it works - it does. 
However, when I keep making steps the D'tor is called on *head* (in the end of the copy constructor) and as a result everything falls apart.
So I have no idea what to do next, or even if I am in the right way.

How should I make the copy constructor? I think I understand why the D'tor is called (I created something and in the end of the block, that something is destroyed - right?), but I don't know how to make it right.

Comment: The main issue here is that you don't seem clear on exactly what "copying a node" should mean. Try to nail this down first. It looks like this might be a node in a linked list.  So, just copying it would then leave you two nodes pointing to the same "next" , which breaks the list structure.  Your code seems to try and fix this by cloning the entire remainder of the list instead. However you then invoke copy-constructor on the next node (which, if successful, would copy that entire node) so you actually end up nearly squaring your list!  Also, you shallow-copy `data`.

Comment: Given that it is not very clear what copying a node means, my suggestion would be to disable the copy-constructor; and add a function called `clone` which makes a copy of all nodes and data.    You certainly can have a move-constructor and move-assignment operator though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the copy constructor is to make an 'exact copy' of the passed object. So depending on the semantics of `data` and `next` pointers you would simply assign them using an initialiser list:

```
Node(const Node& node): data(node.data), next(node.next) {}
```

Since this is just like expected default behaviour (copy members), you can simply omit the copy constructor and the compiler will generate a suitable one by default.

Note that you can definitely create a pointer to a `const` object: what the compiler is complaining about is that the type declaration for your pointer loses the `const` bit in the process.

Second note: for a deep copy you could use something like:

```
Node(const Node& node): 
    data(node.data == NULL? NULL: new T(*node.data)),
    next(node.next == NULL? NULL: new Node(*node.next)) {}
```

Of course, in that deep copy scenario your container is taking "ownership" of the member fields (which prompts the question: why are they pointers in the first place?) and should therefore be careful to properly `delete` them in a destructor.

Comment: No, the purpose of overriding the copy constructor is to _not_ make an exact copy.  With your suggestion here, you copy the `data` pointer.  Now, which instance of `Node` is responsible for deleting that pointer?  Although there is no destructor in the example, I presume that this class is responsible for the memory.

Comment: @paddy I agree 'exact' is a perhaps not the right word, but 'functionally equivalent' is definitely part of expected behaviour. I added a deep copy case. From the code as posted it wasn't entirely clear what the intended ownership semantics were.

Comment: Would it create a copy though? If I later change the source Node, would it be changed in the copied Node? I don't want that. I want a full seperate copy.

Comment: @SiuusSE You need to be careful of the difference between copying a pointer, and copying the memory that it points to.

Comment: @SiuusSE with the deep-copy case you should treat Node as the black box that 'owns' whatever stuff data and next point to.

Comment: The deep copy case does not handle `NULL` for either `data`, or `next`, but otherwise it looks reasonable.  It is recursive though, so without proper compiler optimisations, it could overflow the stack on large lists.  The author was trying to implement the iterative solution which does not have this problem.

Comment: @paddy good points, I added the NULL fix. OP may still want to choose to fix up his iterative version using the note on const pointers...

Comment: @user268396 Thank you for helping, but doesnt `new Node(*node.next))` call the same constructor? How will it stop?

Comment: @SiuusSE when `node.next` is NULL, because then the other branch of the ternary operator kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't quite match the statement that you quoted with the error:

```
Node<T>* dummy= &node;
```

But anyway, you can do this:

```
const Node<T>* dummy= &node;
```

Because `node` is `const`, any references or pointers to it must also be `const`.  You also won't be able to call non-const methods on `node`, so any methods you make for data accessors will need to be const-correct.

Comment: Oh sorry about the confusion, thought posting the same code slightly different would be confusing.Anyway, if I make the pointer const, how would I advanced to the next node?

Comment: The pointer itself is not const.  This can be confusing.  The object it points to is const, and the pointer can be modified.  If it was `Node<T> * const dummy`, that would mean the pointer cannot change, but is a pointer to a non-const object.  Finally, `const Node<T> * const dummy` is a const pointer to a const object.  Welcome to C++. =)

Comment: Just to demystify the above, `const Node<T>` is actually a syntactic short-hand for `Node<T> const`.  If you think about it that way, all you need to remember is that the thing just before `const` is the thing being made const.  This applies to functions, data types, and of course a `*`.